# Show in the table the search results when the user clicks in the "Search" button

Tags: php, laravel

I have this 2 methods in the ParticipantController. The index() show some info of all registrations in a conference. Then the search() is for a search form in the view, to show only in the table the results where the user that did the registration has the name like the name introduced by the user in the search form:

```
class ParticipantController extends Controller
{
    public function index($id){
        $conference = Conference::find($id);
        $conference->load('registrations.participants.answers.question');

        return view('participants.index')->with('conference',  $conference);
    }

    public function search($id, Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->get('participant');
        $conference = Conference::findOrFail($id);

        $searchInfo = $conference->load([
            'registrations.participants' => function ($query) use ($name) {
                return $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%');
            },
            'registrations.participants.answers.question'
        ]);

        return view('participants.index', compact('conference'));
    }
}
```

The routes that I have for this methods:

```
  Route::get('conference/edit/{id}/participants',    [ 'uses' => 'ParticipantController@index', 'as'    =>    'participants.index']);

 Route::get('conference/edit/{id}/participants/search', [
    'uses' => 'ParticipantController@search',
    'as'   => 'participants.search'
]);
```

My doubt is how to show the search results in the view after the user enter some data in the search form and click "Search". When the user acesses the participants/index.blade.php all registrations are already listed in a table with the foreach below using the code in the index() method:

```
@foreach($conference->registrations as $registration)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$registration->customer->name}} {{$registration->customer->surname}}</td>
        <td>{{ $registration->status === 'C' ? 'Complete' : 'Incomplete' }}</td>
        <td><a data-regid="{{$registration->id}}"> More details</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

And its working fine the table show the details of all registrations like:

```
User that did the registration       Quantity           Status                Details

  Jake K                               2                Complete            Show
    ...
```

But in this view there is also the search form, my doubt is how to show in the table the search results when the user introduces a name in the search form and click "Search".

HTML of the search form in the view:

```
<form  action="{{ route('participants.search', ['id' => $conference->id] )}}" method="get">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col col-md-6">
            <label for="participant">Search</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type='text' name="participant" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: use jquery data-tables for the list to display. it will auotmatically takes care of search, pagination etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you search action like this

```
public function search($id, Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->get('participant');
    $conference = Conference::with(['registrations.participants' => function() ($query) use ($name){
                       return $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%');
                  },'registrations.participants.answers.question'])->findOrFail($id);

    return view('participants.index', compact('conference'));
}
```

Now if you look carefully both index and search has the same return type `conference` only the difference is in search we have filtered participants.

**OR**

you can just add the search functionality in **index** action too

```
public function index($id, Request $request){
   $name = $request->get('participant');

   if($name){
       $conference = Conference::with(['registrations.participants' => function() ($query) use ($name){
                       return $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%');
                  },'registrations.participants.answers.question'])->findOrFail($id);
   }else{
       $conference = Conference::with('registrations.participants.answers.question')->findOrFail($id);
   }

   return view('participants.index')->with('conference',  $conference);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but thenhow to show the filtered participants in the view? Is necessary to have the same foreach twice? And also the filtered participants results should only appear when the "Search" button is clicked.

Comment: when you click the submit button it render the same view but with filtered result

Answer (score 0):

You can use datatables 
Link : https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables

Check  . this will solve your problem .

Comment: Thanks, do you know where is the html for the seach bar and results per page?

Comment: Check js files. Search box and results per page created in javascript files.

Answer (score 0):

This would help you with what you need - https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap

Comment: Thanks, do you know where is the html for the seach bar and results per page?

Comment: That is added by the library itself, you just need to initialize datatable on your content table as shown -
$('#your_table_id').DataTable();